# SQL Using ORDER BY with UNION doesn't sort numbers correctly (e.g. 10 before 8)

Tags: sql, sql-order-by, union

I've tried looking for the answer, and read many threads on this site, but still can't find the answer I'm looking for.

I am trying to sort a series of numbers that are real look-ups and also one * which isn't, I can sort fine when I don't need to add the fake * but not after.

I have tried

```
SELECT DISTINCT MasterTable.ClassName, MasterTable.ClassYear
FROM MasterTable
UNION ALL
SELECT DISTINCT "*" As [ClassName], "1" As [ClassYear]
FROM MasterTable
ORDER BY MasterTable.ClassYear;
```

And

```
SELECT DISTINCT MasterTable.ClassName, MasterTable.ClassYear
FROM (
   SELECT DISTINCT MasterTable.ClassName, MasterTable.ClassYear FROM MasterTable
   UNION
   SELECT DISTINCT "*" As [ClassName], "1" As [ClassYear] FROM MasterTable
)
ORDER BY MasterTable.ClassYear;
```

But both return the ClassYear as 1, 10, 12, 8... rather than 1, 8, 10, 12....

Any help would be much appreciated,
Thanks :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

MasterTable.ClassYear is varchar so it will sort as a string.

You'll have to convert it in the query or fix the column type.

For the 2nd clause, you also need only:

```
SELECT "*" As [ClassName], "1" As [ClassYear] --No FROM MasterTable
```

However, you can "cheat" and do this. Here 1 will be int and will force a conversion to int from the 1st clause because

```
SELECT "*" As [ClassName], 1 As [ClassYear]  --force int. And fixed on edit
UNION ALL
SELECT DISTINCT MasterTable.ClassName, MasterTable.ClassYear
FROM MasterTable
ORDER BY ClassYear; --no table ref needed
```

Comment: I need to put "FROM MasterTable" in above the Union all, but it works now. Thanks :)

Comment: Remove DISTINCT from above the UNION ALL sorry

Answer (score 2):

It's property sorting those values as strings.  If you want them in numerical order, try something like `Cast(MasterTable.ClassYear AS int)`, either in the select or in the order by, or both, depending on how you end up structuring your query.

And instead of `SELECT ..., "1" As [ClassYear]`, write `SELECT ..., 1 As [ClassYear]`.

Answer (score 1):

You are returning the year as a string, not a number. That means that it's sorted as text, not numerically.

Either return the year as a number, or convert the value into a number when sorting it.

Comment: @Tim: "1" will be converted to the datatype of the columns because int has higher precedence than varchar. Unless I'm missing something, the table column should be varchar

Comment: @Tim: If the field is a number in the database, then it's the `"1"` value in the second query that determines the data type. If you change it to `1`, the data type will stay numerical.

Comment: I missed that. Thank you both :)

Comment: @Guffa: `SELECT 1 AS foo UNION ALL SELECT 'bar'` = fail. The precedence is over all UNION clauses, not the last one. Also fail: `SELECT 'bar' AS foo UNION ALL SELECT 1`

Comment: @gbn: That is true for an SQL Server database, but that's not what's used here. Notice the quotation marks used as string delimiters.